# Counts word in String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, count, cpu-word

I am writing a code to count different words from string array in java and then storing these different words in an array and there count in another array.
If string array is like String[] appName ={"123", "abc", "Twitter", "123", "abc","123","Twitter", "abc","abc"};
 then in one array {"123","abc","Twitter"} shoud come while in other array there count.
But there is a exception coming in line 21. Any help will be appriciable.

```
public class counts {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static  void countWords(String[] appName){
          int count =1;
          int[] count1 = new int[appName.length];


          String[] array= new String[12];

            for(int k= 0 ;k< appName.length;k++)

            {
                 if(array.length>0)
                 {
                for(int l =0; l<array.length;l++)
                {
                if(!array[l].equals(appName[k])|| array[l]== null)

                {
                    array[k] = appName[k];
                }
                }
                System.out.println(array[k]);
                 }
                 }
          for (int i=0; i<appName.length; i++){
          String temp1 = appName[i];
          //System.out.println(temp + " ");


          count = 1;
          for(int j=i+1; j<appName.length; j++){
          String temp2= appName[j];
          if(temp1.equals(temp2))
          {
              count++;
          }




          }
           count1[i] = count;

           System.out.println(count1[i]);
          }

      }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String[] appName = {"123", "abc", "Twitter", "123", "abc","123","Twitter", "abc","abc"};
          countWords(appName);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just putting all of the `String`s into a `Set<String>`? Also, always post the stack trace of any exception; don't just say you get one.

Comment: Add them all into a `HashSet`. It will make sure no duplicates are added. Then just put it to array.

Comment: Do you have to solve the problem this way?  If you are familiar with using HashMap, specifically `HashMap<String, Integer>` , you can store each string with a count of the number of times it has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You shoudl check for null first before operating on a variable

```
if(!array[l].equals(appName[k])|| array[l]== null)
```

becomes

```
if(array[l]== null||!array[l].equals(appName[k]))
```

but to use a `Set<String>` would be better

Answer (score 0):

To get unique values, you can do the following:

```
Set<String> mySet= new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(appName));
String[] distinctAppName= mySet.toArray(new String[mySet.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way. This may help you.

```
public class Counts {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] appName = {"123", "abc", "Twitter", "123", "abc", 
                                             "123", "Twitter", "abc", "abc"};
    countWords(appName);
}

public static void countWords(String[] appName) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String i : appName) {
        Integer val = map.get(i);
        if (val == null) {
            val = 0;
        }
        map.put(i, val + 1);
    }
    String[] uniqueStr = new String[map.size()];
    int[] count = new int[map.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        uniqueStr[i] = entry.getKey();
        count[i] = entry.getValue();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("unique String array: "+ Arrays.toString(uniqueStr));
    System.out.println("String count array: "+ Arrays.toString(count));
}
}
```

Live [demo](http://ideone.com/KPKERw)